# Can I make an assignment operator on a base class that returns sub-class type

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Sorry for the bad title... I have a base class like:

```
template<class T>
class GPtr
{
public:
    typedef T BaseType;

    GPtr& operator=(const BaseType& rhs)
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

I often want to make subclassed specializations like:

```
class GraphicPtr : public GPtr<Graphic>
{
...
};
```

However my base-class assignment operator still returns `GPtr<Graphic>` not `GraphicPtr` and it's annoying to have to copy-paste code in case the core assignment operator functionality should change later.

Is there a neat way to define the base-class assignment operator so it returns the type of the actual class in use?

Comment: Why not write function, that really do assign and call it in all derived classes?

Comment: What is the real problem to solve here? Not the syntactic issues of your solution, but the real problem for which the solution seems to be having an assignment operator that returns a reference to the derived type. There are a couple of things that are not clear, like why `GPtr<>::operator=` takes a `T` argument (incorrectly named `BaseType`), what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, the base class has no idea of it's children. You may add a template parameter that will be the derived class and use it.

```
template<class T, class Derived>
class GPtr
{
public:
    typedef T BaseType;

    Derived& operator=(const BaseType& rhs)
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: I wondered if this might be possible. However, what happens if I want to use `GPtr` directly sometimes, not always in a subclass?

Comment: I tried to make the second parameter GPtr<T>, but it's impossible, because here we need infinite specialization: GPtr<T, GPtr<T, GPtr<T, GPtr<T, ...>>>>. Maybe here you should try something different :)

Comment: That's the same problem I was seeing. It seems the kind of thing which should be possible but I don't know templates well enough

Comment: @John if you want a standalone `GPtr`, it won't need the `operator=` returning a derived class reference. Therefore the standalone class and the one with the reference returning `op=` have different functionality and obviously have to be two different classes. The CRTP with the `op=` may derive from the standalone class, though.

Comment: Well, we still can make something like that: make the default value for second parameter void and use SFINAE to distinguish between the void case and the case when 'Derived' is some derived class.

Comment: @lisyarus sfinae won't benecessary, a simple trait will do: `typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_void<Derived>::value, GPtr, Derived>::type AssignmentReturn;` You will however need a using declaration in the derived class: http://ideone.com/beQ0DJ

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) instead?

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Derived>
class GPtr
{
public:
    typedef Derived DerivedType;

    GPtr& operator=(const GPtr& rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "GPtr::operator=" << std::endl;

        return *this;
    }
};

class GraphicDerived : public GPtr<GraphicDerived>
{
    public: 

        GraphicDerived& operator=(const GraphicDerived& rhs)
        {
            std::cout << "GraphicDerived::operator=" << std::endl;
            // Inheiriting shadows the name of the base operator= which 
            // needs to be explicitly called.
            GPtr<GraphicDerived>::operator=(rhs); 
            return *this;
        };
};

class Graphic {};

using namespace std;

int main()
{


    GraphicDerived one; 
    GraphicDerived two;

    cout << "derived assignment: " << endl;
    one = two;

    GPtr<Graphic> ptrOne;
    GPtr<Graphic> ptrTwo;

    cout << "GPtr assignment stnadalone : " << endl;

    ptrOne = ptrTwo; 
};
```

Results with:

```
derived assignment: 
GraphicDerived::operator=
GPtr::operator=
GPtr assignment stnadalone : 
GPtr::operator=
```

Comment: Maybe I am misreading but that seems to have two problems... 1)I still have to write a separate assignment operator in the derived class... 2)The base class is already templated on the type it wraps which is not the same as the subclass

Comment: 1) Adding a separate assignment operator in the derived class makes sense if the derived class has additional attributes compared to the base class. 2) Okay I get what you mean, here's a counter question: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for does not really make sense. When the base object is being assigned, it cannot possibly know which of the potentially infinite number of derived types it is being called from, and thus cannot return a different type in each case. Furthermore, even if that was possible, it would not be possible to use that in real code.

C++ resolves everything but polymorphic calls at runtime, and even for polymorphic calls it only delays finding the exact override, but not the signature (i.e. even with covariant return types, the return type of the base override will be used.

Technically it can be done, with or without templates, *but* all of them exhibit the same core issue: The base class can only be a base class for a single type, the type returned by the assignment operator, limiting the usability as a *base* class.

**What is the real problem that you want to solve?**

The approach that you are taking does not seem appropriate. It would be much better if you explained what you are trying to achieve so that people can suggest other approaches.

Comment: Exactly what I commented. I thought I was missing something. 1+.

Comment: It's not a normal inheritance though, it's templated - so for each specialized variant a whole separate class is created rather than having real base class methods. So the assignment operator is the same in every case, applied to the templated types involved. @lisyarus' answer is closest to what I've done

Comment: @John: Whether it is a template or not is almost orthogonal. There is nothing inhibiting 'struct a : base<int> {}; struct b : base<int> {};`. Unless the restriction is part of your *design* (which you could enforce in C++11, but is not enforced in your code). If that is the case, then you are *abusing* inheritance and should be using composition instead, there is no reason not to have `GPtr<Graphic>` as a member of `GraphicDerived`, and I still don't see the reason for the assignment... does the implicitly defined one not work for some reason? (Why?)