# Recursive template pattern; when is type finalized?

Tags: c++, templates

Linked to my other question ([Can I make an assignment operator on a base class that returns sub-class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210582/can-i-make-an-assignment-operator-on-a-base-class-that-returns-sub-class-type)) I have this construct, the idea is I want to derive specialized types from `GPtrBase` without having to re-write an assignment operator every time:

```
template<class BaseType,class Self>
class GPtrBase
{
public:
    ...

    Self& operator=(const BaseType& rhs)
    {
        ...
        return *this;
    }

};
```

However when I specialize like:

`class GDrawablePtr : public GPtrBase<MyDrawable,GDrawablePtr>`

I get errors:

> > 'return' : cannot convert from 'GPtrBase<Base,Self>' to 'GDrawablePtr &'

I thought a template class was generated based on the specializations used, so shouldn't `*this` be of type `GDrawablePtr` in the first place?

**updated:** I note if I add `using GPtrBase::operator=;` it then works, even though `GDrawablePtr` definitely does *not* define any operators.

Comment: The code you posted works as is: http://ideone.com/4grkfv

Comment: @icepack that is very weird. Eiter it's a quirk of my compiler (VC++ 2005) or some detail of the full code is to blame. I'll investigate with less-simplified version to check.

Comment: @icepack no it doesn't. The `operator=` there is ignored due to the type of its argument. See program output of http://ideone.com/EWrVAh. Because it is not needed, the compiler doesn't try to compile it, hence the missing error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast to dynamic polymorphism where the `this`-pointer in `virtual` functions is automatically downcast from base to derived, you need to use an explicit `static_cast` to the derived class

```
template<class BaseType,class Self>
class GPtrBase
{
public:
    ...

    Self& operator=(const BaseType& rhs)
    {
        ...
        return static_cast<Self&>(*this);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

> I thought a template class was generated based on the specializations used, so shouldn't *this be of type GDrawablePtr in the first place?

It seems you put more into template instantiation than there actually is. A class template is just that: a template that when given its arguments generates a class. It doesn't bind the template arguments to the resultant class in any additional way.

In particular, the fact that you are inheriting from the instantiated class at the point of instantiation doesn't change anything in the class's definition. It is still independent class with it's own (albeit somewhat complicated) type and as such it is no different than any other base class defined without template machinery. For example there is no implicit conversion from pointer to base class to pointer to any of its subclasses regardless of how the base or the subclasses were created.